# TextField text gets cleared while tapping one of TextField

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am getting some strange issue where one of TextField always gets clears if you tap on it.

```
class MyEditText extends StatefulWidget {
  static String tag = "MyEditText";
  @override
  MyEditTextState createState() => MyEditTextState();
}

class MyEditTextState extends State<MyEditText> {
  String results = "";
  final TextEditingController controller = new TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController controller1 = new TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final email = TextField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: 'Enter Email',
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 10.0, 20.0, 10.0)),
    );

    final password = TextField(
      obscureText: true,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: 'Enter Password',
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 10.0, 20.0, 10.0),
      ),
    );

    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: new Text("EditText Sample"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
      ),
      body: new Container(
        child: new Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[email, password],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am using statful widget for it and all classes from where this screen launch also statful.

**Note:** If I comment out all TextEditingController and its usage, everything works fine, SO I m not getting what is wrong with TextEditingController

Comment: please expand your code to show where you use `email` & `password` variables, as well as controllers declaration.

Comment: I tried to put those TextFields to my demo and it works. You may need to provide more details of how you are using them.

Comment: @George: Please check the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the updated code.

The reason your `TextEditingController` get cleared is because you declare the variables inside of `State<MyEditText>`. When the State gets re-initialized - those variables do, too.

I can see 2 ways to solve this:

#### #1 - Move controllers out of the State to the parent class, passing them as arguments

Controllers are declared and maintained outside of `MyEditText` widget - in the parent class.

```dart
class MyEditText extends StatefulWidget {
  MyEditText({ Key key, this.emailController, this.passwordController }): super(key: key);

  final TextEditingController emailController;
  final TextEditingController passwordController;

  static String tag = "MyEditText";

  @override
  MyEditTextState createState() => MyEditTextState();
}

class MyEditTextState extends State<MyEditText> {
  String results = "";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // ...
    TextField(
      controller: widget.emailController,
      // ...,
    ),
    TextField(
      controller: widget.passwordController,
      // ...,
    ),
    // ...
  }
}
```

Then you declare controllers in your parent class and pass them as arguments to `MyEditText`:

```dart
final emailController = TextEditingController();
final passwordController = TextEditingController();
// ...
MyEditText(
  emailController: emailController,
  passwordController: passwordController,
)
```

---

#### #2 - Reuse controllers from the old state on `didUpdateWidget` call

Controllers can be declared outside of `MyEditText` class, but if they were not - widget creates and maintains `TextEditingController` on its own.

```dart
class MyEditText extends StatefulWidget {
  MyEditText({ Key key, this.emailController, this.passwordController }): super(key: key);

  final TextEditingController emailController;
  final TextEditingController passwordController;

  static String tag = "MyEditText";

  @override
  MyEditTextState createState() => MyEditTextState();
}

class MyEditTextState extends State<MyEditText> {

  TextEditingController _emailController;
  TextEditingController _passwordController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (widget.emailController == null)
      _emailController = TextEditingController();
    if (widget.passwordController == null)
      _passwordController = TextEditingController();
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(MyEditText oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);

    if (widget.emailController == null && oldWidget.emailController != null)
      _emailController = TextEditingController.fromValue(oldWidget.emailController.value);
    else if (widget.emailController != null && oldWidget.emailController == null)
      _emailController = null;

    if (widget.passwordController == null && oldWidget.passwordController != null)
      _passwordController = TextEditingController.fromValue(oldWidget.passwordController.value);
    else if (widget.passwordController != null && oldWidget.passwordController == null)
      _passwordController = null;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // ...
    TextField(
      controller: _emailController ?? widget.emailController,
      // ...,
    ),
    TextField(
      controller: _passwordController ?? widget.passwordController,
      // ...,
    ),
    // ...
  }
  // ...
}
```

---

Both methods are similar except that the second one regulates `State<MyEditText>` variables on its own.

I will leave it to you to decide which one is more suitable in your case.

Let me know if this helped.

Answer (score 0):

```html
 

   TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();
    TextEditingController controller1 = TextEditingController();

    final email = TextField(
      controller: emailController,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person_outline, color: Colors.grey),
          hintText: 'Enter Email',
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 10.0, 20.0, 10.0)),
    );

    final password = TextField(
      controller1: passwordController,
      obscureText: true,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock_open, color: Colors.grey),
        hintText: 'Enter Password',
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 10.0, 20.0, 10.0),
      ),
    );

     clearName() {
        controller.text = '';
        controller1.text = '';
     }
 
 //call the clearName function wherever needed
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this way

```
TextFormField(
                cursorColor: Colors.white,
                autofocus: false,
                keyboardType:
                TextInputType.emailAddress,
                controller: _textEditingControllerEmail,
                ),

 TextFormField(
               autofocus: false,
               controller:_textEditingControllerPassword,
               cursorColor: Colors.white,
               obscureText: true,
               ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Just override the didUpdateWidget() like below.  This works only if you stay on the same screen.  Moving to a different screen will reinitialize everything.

```
class MyEditText extends StatefulWidget {
  static String tag = "MyEditText";
  // Move the controllers to the widget.
  final TextEditingController controller = new TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController controller1 = new TextEditingController();

  @override
  MyEditTextState createState() => MyEditTextState();
}

class MyEditTextState extends State<MyEditText> {
  String results = "";
  
  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(oldWidget) // Override it and copy the old ones over if not null
  {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    if((widget.controller != null) && (oldWidget.controller != null))
       widget.controller.text = oldWidget.controller.text;
    if((widget.controller1 != null) && (oldWidget.controller1 != null))
       widget.controller1.text = oldWidget.controller1.text;
    
  }
  ... //The rest of your code
```